# como puedo ordenar los rut de mayor a menor

Tags: java, java-swing, javafx, java-8, java-ee

Valido el Nro de  rut de la forma XXXXXXXX-X  en java

me refiero si tengo dos rut ejemplo 18365987-1 y 19876398-0 el rut mayor debería ser el que empieza con 19.
estos rut deben ser guardados en un archivo txt y a su ves deben ser ordenados de menor a mayor de esta manera

19567876-2, 18564678-9 ,17324565-2

```
public class Validar {
 public static Boolean validaRut ( String rut ) {
                    
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+-[0-9kK]{1}$");

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(rut);

        if ( matcher.matches() == false ) return false;

        String[] stringRut = rut.split("-");//separa el rut en dos

        return stringRut[1].toLowerCase().equals(dv(stringRut[0]));
         
               
    }

     operación de validación 

    
    public static String dv ( String rut ) {
    
            Integer M=0,S=1,T=Integer.parseInt(rut);
    
            for (;T!=0;T=(int) Math.floor(T/=10))
    
                S=(S+T%10*(9-M++%6))%11;
    
            return ( S > 0 ) ? String.valueOf(S-1) : "k"
```

Comment: En tu pregunta falta indicar cuál es el criterio para considerar un número de RUT mayor que otro. Con ejemplos. Puedes [edit] todo lo que desees la pregunta.

Comment: el criterio se vasa en los dos primeros números

Comment: me refiero  si tengo dos rut ejemplo 18365987-1 y 19876398-0  el rut mayor debería ser el que empieza con 19

Comment: mira estos rut deben ser guardados en un archivo txt  y a su ves deben ser ordenados de menor a mayor de esta manera 19567876-2, 18564678-9 ,17324565-2

Comment: Pero por qué tan difícil seguir una indicación tan sencilla?

Comment: disculpa  si no me se expresar pero agradecería la ayuda

Comment: no te entendí pero  lo entiendes ahora ?

Comment: podrias usar un treeMap como Key guardas stringRut[0] y Value stringRut[1] ordenas mediante el K y luego concatenas tanto K como V en una lista